# replace all digit in a string with $ character

Tags: javascript

Write a JavaScript program to replace all digit in a string with $ character.

```js
function replace_first_digit(input_str) {
  return input_str.replace(/[0-9]/, '$');
}
console.log(replace_first_digit("abc1dabc"));
console.log(replace_first_digit("p3ytho2n"));
console.log(replace_first_digit("ab10cabc"));
```

Comment: whats your output? try `/\d/g` instead of `/[0-9]/`

Comment: So what is your problem? this code does the expectation

Comment: it's currently replacing the first occurrence only?

Comment: @SachithWickramaarachchi, no, it doesn't. _All_ numbers have to be replaced.

Comment: erm.... `replace_first_digit` is the name of the method, and youre asking about replacing _all_ digits.

Answer (score 4):

You need the addition of the `g` modifier to make the `replace` work on multiple matches

```js
function replace_first_digit(input_str) {
  return input_str.replace(/[0-9]/g, '$');
}
console.log(replace_first_digit("abc1dabc"));
console.log(replace_first_digit("p3ytho2n"));
console.log(replace_first_digit("ab10cabc"));
```

However, the naming of the function as `replace_first_digit` makes me suspect that you might have misunderstood the requirement and your original code was correct!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`g`-modifier/flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global)

```js
const replace_first_digit = input_str => input_str.replace(/[0-9]/g, '$');
console.log(replace_first_digit("abc1dabc"));
console.log(replace_first_digit("p3ytho2n"));
console.log(replace_first_digit("ab10cabc"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick

```js
function replace_first_digit(input_str) {
  return input_str.replace(/\d/g, '$');
}
console.log(replace_first_digit("abc1dabc"));
console.log(replace_first_digit("p3ytho2n"));
console.log(replace_first_digit("ab10cabc"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function replace_all_digits(input_str) {
  return input_str.split('').map((i)=> isNaN(i) ? i : '$').join('')
}
console.log(replace_all_digits("abc1dabc"));
console.log(replace_all_digits("p3ytho2n"));
console.log(replace_all_digits("ab10cabc"));
```

Iterates over each letter and checks if it can be a number. If so, returns a `$` otherwise the letter.